# wcf duplex call through from host to guest under vmware (nat?)

Tags: .net, wcf, vmware, duplex, nat

i have installed an xp under vmware workstation and i can ping the guest with the adress 192.168.126.131 - so i've started a wcf duplex service, which works fine if i start srv and client under my host system (using localhost everywhere as path) - but if i start the service srv under the guest i can access http://192.168.126.131:18000/MyService?wsdl but it won't work - i have no idea why. also if i use vmware virtual network editor to forward the port to host won't work :-S

Answer (score 0):

have you checked your firewall in your vm? does it work when you disable the firewalls (windows firewall, third party tool)?

What kind of network connection do you use in vmware? (NAT, Bridged, Host-Only)?

Comment: using nat... firewall is diasabled!

Comment: is net.tcp port sharing service enabled? 
have you tried to enable/disable it?
(i had problem with that, even when i don't used it in the bindings ==> portSharingEnabled="false")

please add your service.model configuration to your question.